# $f^{-1}(C) $ is connected $\forall C \subset Y$ connected.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \tau_{X})$, $(Y, \tau_{Y})$  be topological spaces. $X, Y$ are Hausdorff and compact spaces and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuos. if $f^{-1}(y)$ is connected $\forall y \in Y$, prove that $f^{-1}(C) $ is connected $\forall C \subset Y$ connected.

Note: If $Y$ is not Hausdorff show that the result does not have.

I am a little confused, I have the following:

Suppose $ f^{-1}(C) $ is not connected for $ C \subset Y$ connected, that is, there are open $ U, V $ of $ f ^{-1}(C) \subset X $ such that $f^{-1}(C)=U \cup V$ and $U \cap \overline{V}= \emptyset= \overline{U} \cap V$, since $\overline{U} $ and $\overline{V} $ are closed of a compact Hausdorff space then $ \overline{U }$ and $ \overline{V} $ are compact, by the continuity of $ f $, $f(\overline{U}), \ f(\overline{V}) \subset Y$ compacts subsets, being $ Y $ Hausdorff, these are closets.

Note that $ f (\overline {U}) \cap C, \ f (\overline {U}) \cap C \subset C $.

Let's see that $ C=( f (\overline {U}) \cap C)  \cup (  f (\overline {V}) \cap C) $ and $ (f (\overline{U}) \cap C ) \cap  \overline{ (f (\overline {U}) \cap C)}=\emptyset= \overline{(f (\overline {V}) \cap C )} \cap  (f (\overline {V}) \cap C) $.

For $( f (\overline {U}) \cap C)  \cup (  f (\overline {V}) \cap C) = (f(\overline{U}) \cup f(\overline{V})) \cap C$ since $f^{-1}(C)=U \cup V$ and $f$ is continuos then $C=f(U) \cup f(V)$ so $(f(\overline{U}) \cup f(\overline{V})) \cap C=C$ ... I don't know how to prove that $ (f (\overline{U}) \cap C ) \cap  \overline{ (f (\overline {U}) \cap C)}=\emptyset= \overline{(f (\overline {V}) \cap C )} \cap  (f (\overline {V}) \cap C) $.

For the counterexample:
Let's take the part-defined function:
$f(x) = 1-x $ if $x \leq $ and $f(x)=x $ if $x \geq 2 $  it is continuous, its path is connected, but the domain, which is the inverse image of the range, is not connected.

Thanks for the help and suggestions.

Comment: Why should $f(\overline{U}), \ f(\overline{V})$ be connected?

Comment: sorry it was a mistake i meant closed.

Answer (score 1):

The compactness is a red herring. What matters is that $f: X \to Y$ is a quotient map. Under the assumptions of $X$ compact and $Y$ Hausdorff, any continuous $f: X \to Y$ that is onto, is quotient.

And if $f: X \to Y$ is quotient, onto and has connected fibres (i.e. all sets $F_y:=f^{-1}[\{y\}], y \in Y$ are connected) has the property that $f^{-1}[C]$ is connected whenever $C$ is. Several proofs of this can be found on this site.

A counter example to dropping Hausdorffness : $X= \{0\} \cup \{\frac1n\mid n \in \Bbb N^+\}$ in the Euclidean topology (compact and Hausdorff). $Y=X$ as a set but in the cofinite topology (compact but not Hausdorff), $f(x)=x$, which is continuous and 1-1 (so fibres are all singletons and thus connected). But $f$ is not quotient and $Y$ is connected while $X=f^{-1}[Y]$ is not.

Comment: Another simple counterexample is this: Let $F$ be any finite set, $X$ = $F$ with discrete topology, $Y$  = $F$ with trivial topology and $f = id$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Sure, but I was going for a $T_1$ counterexample. That rules out the finite spaces.

Comment: Okay, I understand!

Comment: under the test I mentioned above I won't get to $ A $ is disconnected?